# I sent a Bitcoin transaction to myself using Bitcoin Core and it is not broadcast?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, broadcast

I am not asking why the transaction is not confirmed, I am asking why it does not show as being broadcast even though it is in the log.

I sent a Bitcoin transaction to myself some time ago using Bitcoin Core, and it just says it is in the mempool after 55 days - I just noticed. Usually, it says broadcast through x nodes. The balance is, of course, showing in my wallet.

`Status: 0/unconfirmed, in memory pool
Date: 1/12/17 20:48
Total debit: -0.00004551 BTC
Total credit: 0.00004551 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00001001 BTC
Net amount: -0.00001001 BTC
Transaction ID: 766dd7ea920a7f40579ee805e649a2fc886e89e9b514f653837b8ab219825af9
Transaction total size: 225 bytes
Output index: 0`

I know that the fee might seem a bit low but I did use the fee recommendations, and another transaction with the same fee sent elsewhere at the same time confirmed some time ago.

In my `debug.log` this time after restarting the node I see:
`AddToWallet 766dd7ea920a7f40579ee805e649a2fc886e89e9b514f653837b8ab219825af9`

Previously I used to see a `debug.log` message for rebroadcasting transaction after node restart, which I assume now was this one even though there is no broadcast count, but I cannot see that message yet this node restart. EDIT: log message took a while and looks like this:
`2018-01-24 10:51:10 Relaying wtx 766dd7ea920a7f40579ee805e649a2fc886e89e9b514f653837b8ab219825af9
2018-01-24 10:51:10 ResendWalletTransactions: rebroadcast 1 unconfirmed transactions`

What needs to be done to resolve this?

Comment: @Alpha I have seen that canonical question and understand the confirmation process, fees, transaction bandwith limit, etc. but that I know of it does not answer my question - unless an explanation of how it does is necessary?

Comment: It seem's that your ultimate question is "What needs to be done to resolve this?" In response, @Alpha's linked article states "Nothing. The next best thing is to cancel and resend the transaction."